# Pusing an update to a nuget package

Tags: package, nuget, push

I have created my own nuget package and was able to get that package in a private feed.

I now want to update that package with a new version.

I changed the Version in the nuspec file from "1.0" to "1.1"
like so:

```
<version>1.1</version>
```

This successfully generated the "FakeCoreObjects.1.1.nupkg" file.

I then run the following via command line (secret data is obscured):

```
nuget push FakeCoreObjects.1.1.nupkg my-api-key-is-here -Source http://nuget.PrivateFeedWebSite.net/F/smicalizzi_test
```

And got this message:

```
Publishing FakeCoreObjects 1.1 to the live feed...
Your package was published to the feed.
```

So far so good...

Next I attempted to update that package in a project that I was referencing it. I cannot. I can only "Install" the new version which leaves behind a package reference to the old package. I also cannot install the old version of the package anymore.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what I was doing wrong. When I was getting the package from the package manager console I was missing the source feed.

```
update-Package FakeRave.FakeCode -Source http://myFeedLocationWentHere/Hooray
```

As for the package manager in Visual Studio I was looking in the wrong place :( I was looking in "Online" instead of "Updates" (I feel so dumb :( )